# Tool for accessing android files on a linux pc over wi-fi

Tags: files

What is the best app to browse, explore and access android files on a Linux machine over wifi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTPServer is very good, SwiFTP is another option.  I believe they're both in the Market.

Comment: Matthew, do those two work as regular FTP clients as well, i.e. login to a remote server and manage files on it?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I searched a bit and didn't see any apps that did both.

Answer (score 3):

I use [QuickSSHd](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quicksshd/com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd). It costs $1.50 US but is worthwhile for me because it gives command line access as well as full root filesystem access. Does require root.

Answer (score 2):

I use [WiFi File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-file-explorer/com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorer).  It's for accessing (and moving, etc) files on your phone, nothing else, but it does it wonderfully.